# Stored Procedure Count(*)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCorrespondingRespcode]
@rc char(3)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @webRcCount int

    SELECT webRc, COUNT(*) as webRcCount  
    FROM payterm.response_codes_mapping  
    WHERE rc = @rc GROUP BY webRc
END
```

How can I set `@webRcCount` with the value of the `webRcCount`? I need to do `if  @webRcCount = 1  print'ok'`

Comment: You have included a `GROUP BY` ... so you aren't guaranteed to have a single value.

Comment: According to Mathew's comment, what's the exact condition on which you'd like to print "ok"?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @webRcCount = COUNT(*) 
FROM payterm.response_codes_mapping 
WHERE rc = @rc

SELECT @webRcCount AS [WebRCCount]
```

That should do it...

Comment: If he does this, he doesn't get his grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to count *distinct* `webRc` values in the table? If so, use this instead:

```
SELECT @webRcCount = COUNT(DISTINCT webRC) 
FROM payterm.response_codes_mapping 
WHERE rc = @rc;
```